# Game in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm new here. I'm trying to make a game with Android Studio and I've a problem: the Android Studio emulator load every Activity and the background loop of the game, my phone doesn't the background loop game.
This is my code.

BackGround Java class

```
package com.example.francesco.fraedogame;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;


public class Background {
    private Bitmap image;
    private int x, y, dx;

    public Background(Bitmap res){
        image = res;
    }
    public void update(){
        x+=dx;
        if(x<-GamePanel.WIDTH){
            x = 0;
        }
    }
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, x, y, null);
        if(x < 0){
            canvas.drawBitmap(image, x+GamePanel.WIDTH, y, null);
        }
    }
    public void setVector(int dx){
        this.dx = dx;
    }
}
```

MainThread Java class (for the loop game)

```
package com.example.francesco.fraedogame;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;


public class MainThread extends Thread {
    private int FPS = 30;
    private double averageFPS;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private boolean running;
    private static Canvas canvas;

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GamePanel gamePanel){
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        long startTime;
        long timeMillis;
        long waitTime;
        long totalTime = 0;
        int frameCount = 0;
        long targetTime = 1000/FPS;

        while(running){
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            canvas = null;

            //Lock Canvas
            try{
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                    this.gamePanel.update();
                    this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            finally {
                if(canvas!=null){
                    try{
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            timeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000;
            waitTime = targetTime - timeMillis;
            try{
                this.sleep(waitTime);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            totalTime += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            frameCount++;
            if(frameCount == FPS){
                averageFPS = 1000/((totalTime/frameCount)/1000000);
                frameCount = 0;
                totalTime = 0;
                System.out.println(averageFPS);
            }
        }
    }
    public void setRunning(boolean b){
        running = b;
    }
}
```

The GamePanel Java class

```
package com.example.francesco.fraedogame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    //Image Background dimension
    public static final int WIDTH = 856;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
    private MainThread thread;
    private Background bg;

    public GamePanel(Context context){
        super(context);
        //Add the callBack to the SurfaceHolder for intercept events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        //GamePanel focusable for handle events
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        //End the loop
        boolean retry = true;
        while(retry){
            try{
                thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            retry = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        //Set the Background
        bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background));
        bg.setVector(-5);
        //Start the loop
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    //Handle touch screen motion events
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    public void update(){
        bg.update();
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        final float scaleFactoryX = getWidth()/WIDTH;
        final float scaleFactoryY = getHeight()/HEIGHT;
        if (canvas != null) {
            final int savedState= canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scaleFactoryX, scaleFactoryY);
            bg.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
        }
    }

}
```

The manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.francesco.fraedogame">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomePage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondHome" />
        <activity android:name=".game"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name=".options" />
        <activity android:name=".records"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: **Please** explain this a bit better `the Android Studio emulator load every Activity and the background loop of the game, my phone doesn't the background loop game.` Maybe attach some screenshots.

Comment: Also please narrow the problem down to a minimal example of what is happening. You are posting a lot of code with a pretty unclear explanation of what the issue is. I don't think anyone here is going to be interested in wading through all that looking for mistakes. Please narrow the issue down to just a few lines of code and state the specific problem.

Comment: The app is composed in this way:
an Home Page, with 4 button: Play, Options, Records and Exit. When I press play, the game start. The emulator shows the game, the phone doesn't, it shows only a black screen.